# getting record of manually made changes in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

My fellow admins have made some changes manually in phpmyadmin. I want to get the record of the changes they have made. Is it possible to get that??

Comment: Compare against a backup from before the changes.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can remember from phpMyadmin, when you install it you have a '*config.sample.inc.php*' file which you copy to set up the actual '*config.inc.php*' which contains all the configurations. You could use a file difference tool to compare both files and you could see the differences between the original and how it currently is. This is not an exact way but will offer insight into changes made. The only other way that I know off hand is if the config files are under version control, in which case you can compare previous versions.

Hope this helps :)